# Why load test on postgres database getting worse result while changing default parametes to get better performance?

Tags: postgresql, psql, load-testing

I want to have a load test on my postgresql database named `dvdrental`.While using postgres default parameters in postgresql.conf file , my database performance is pretty better than other situations.My node is about 8GB of RAM and 4 cpu cores. The query I used for pgbench is in a file named `sql_query.sql` :

```
    SELECT 
   account.first_name, 
   s1.time as time, 
   random() * (100-0) + 0 AS cpu_usage, 
   random() * (30-26) + 26 * 1024 AS average_mhs, 
   random() * (90-50) + 50 AS temperature, 
   random() * (100-0) + 0 AS fan 
FROM generate_series(
   '2018-10-14', 
   '2021-10-15', 
   INTERVAL '1 day') AS s1(time) 
CROSS JOIN(
   SELECT 
      account_id,
      first_name, 
      last_name 
   FROM account limit 100  
) account 
ORDER BY 
  account.account_id, 
  s1.time;
```

While `account` is a table in `dvdrental` database with `account_id` , `first_name` and `last_name` columns. So the command I use for pgbench is :

```
pgbench -f sql_query.sql -n -r -c 50 -T 400 -j 4 dvdrental
```

The result I get is:

```
pgbench (14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
transaction type: sql_query.sql
scaling factor: 1
query mode: prepared
number of clients: 50
number of threads: 4
duration: 400 s
number of transactions actually processed: 3038
latency average = 6497.161 ms
initial connection time = 79.758 ms
tps = 7.695669 (without initial connection time)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
      6210.604  SELECT
```

then I tried to change parameters to :

```
shared_buffers = "2GB",
effective_cache_size = "6GB",
maintenance_work_mem = "512MB",
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9,
wal_buffers = 16MB,
default_statistics_target = 100,
random_page_cost = 1.1,
effective_io_concurrency = 200,
work_mem = "20971kB",
huge_pages = off,
min_wal_size = "1GB",
max_wal_size = "4GB",
max_worker_processes = 4,
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2,
max_parallel_workers = 4,
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2;
```

And I get this result:

```
pgbench (14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
transaction type: sql_query.sql
scaling factor: 1
query mode: prepared
number of clients: 50
number of threads: 4
duration: 400 s
number of transactions actually processed: 2838
latency average = 7114.727 ms
initial connection time = 409.796 ms
tps = 7.027676 (without initial connection time)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
      7088.570  SELECT
```

Even changing any parameter does not helped.

Comment: Why do you think those changes would improve anything?  What were they before they were changed?  I'm not convinced the difference is even reproducible rather than just random noise or something else which happens to be loading the machine at the same time, you would need to change the configuration back and forth several times to show that.  But it would be better to dig into the execution plan of the query (`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`)

Comment: Pleaser go to [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) and construct an `account` table, provide some sample data and then post all of that back here as well as the link to dbfiddle - notify me by putting `@ + my handle (no space)` in a comment below this. Put **all** extra informatin into the **question** and not in comments.

Comment: @FrankHeikens That is not the network (ping) latency, that is the total latency, which includes not just the network round trip, but also the time to run the actual query.